# async and await following fetch request

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to rework my code that currently uses callbacks to use `async`, `await`. The only thing is that in my current setup i am a little bit confused about how it should be written.

The setup is that:

1. i click a button that triggers `clicker` function
2. `clicker` function triggers `ajax` function
3. `ajax` function does `fetch` request
4. after response is back I need to pass response to `clicker` function

Currently I am getting `undefined` from `ajax` function, could someone help and point out what is the problem?

```js
var ajax = function() {
 fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => { console.log('ajax function', json); return json; })
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
};

var clicker = async function() {
 var a = await ajax();
 console.log('clicker function', a);
};
```

```html
<div onclick="clicker(event, this);">
 Test Me
</div>
```

Comment: _"currently i am getting `undefined` from `ajax` function"_ - because you're not returning anything...

Comment: This is about jQuery, but there's an example on using async/await with fetch right here: https://github.com/you-dont-need-x/you-dont-need-jquery#ajax-get

Comment: Try making your `ajax` function `return fetch(...`. You need to return the promise that you build there in order to make your function awaitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```js
var ajax = async function() {
  try {
    let response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    let json = await response.json();
    console.log('ajax function', json)
    return json;

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  };
};

var clicker = async function() {
  var a = await ajax();
  console.log('clicker function', a);
};
```

```css
.btn { border-radius: 5px; background: #00ff00; width: 80px; padding: 10px;cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<div class="btn" onclick="clicker(event, this);">
  Test Me
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only `await` a promise.

The return value of `ajax()` is `undefined` because it has no return statement.

`fetch` returns a promise, but you don't return it.

Add a return statement:

```
return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
```

Comment: i tested these both, both works, but i must say that answer with `try` seems more convenient, as we can process `json` from response and return it. otherwise by returning `fetch` directly, i need to make processing in clicker function

Comment: @Mevia — No, because you are already doing the `.then(json => { console.log('ajax function', json); return json; })` stuff in your existing code.